# "CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 32" when attempting to attach database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssms, connectivity, visual-studio-2015

I am having trouble connecting to a database I created in SSMS. Keep in mind this is my first time working with databases. All I've done in this database is create some tables and add a few records. What I need to do is connect to this database in Visual Studio 2015. However, when I try to add a connection to a Microsoft SQL Server Database File to my `windows forms application` it says the file is in use and will not let me select it. When I select a different database file I created in SSMS and test the connection it tells me `this database file is not compatible with the current instance of SQL Server. To resolve this issue, you must upgrade the database file by creating a new connection or modify the existing connection to this database file.` Now in order to upgrade a database file, according to MS documentation, is to attach the database. But when I right click the "Database" node in SSMS and click attach and try to add either of the two database `.mdf` files from earlier, it gives me this error:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. 
(Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 32(The process cannot access the file 
because it is being used by another process.) while attempting to open or create the 
physical file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Mestek Database.mdf'. 
(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5123)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=12.00.2000&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=5123&LinkId=20476
```

I ran this query on the database which I guess returns any process using the database.

```
SELECT * FROM sysfiles
```

But this just returns the file path and name of the `.mdf` file and log file.

Answer (score 2):

Do not fear everyone, I fixed my problem. What I had to do was detach the databases that I needed so that they were no longer being used by SSMS. This got rid of the error I was having and allowed me to add a connection to the data source in visual studio.